# Classifier sometimes not affecting document to category

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, document-classification

I'm currently trying to classify some documents to a fixed amount of categories.
The main issue here is that sometimes the classifier seems not finding the proper category. Therefore, the output is empty.

I'm using the following code :

```
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
Y = mlb.fit_transform(y_train_text)

class DenseTransformer(TransformerMixin):
    def transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return X.todense()

    def fit_transform(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        self.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
        return self.transform(X)

    def fit(self, X, y=None, **fit_params):
        return self

classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
    ('to_dense', DenseTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(GaussianNB()))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
all_labels = mlb.inverse_transform(predicted)
```

An example of an output :

```
doc 0 : ""
doc 1 : "news"
doc 2 : "spam"
doc 3 : ""
doc 4 : ""
doc 5 : "news"
doc 6 : "tech-news"
```

Isnt the principle is to assign a category to each documents using similarity comparison knowing tf-idf ? 
(tf-idf gives a representation of the frequencies of words in a document)

EDIT: **sample** code

```
X_train = np.array(["new york is a hell of a town",
                    "new york was originally dutch",
                    "the big apple is great",
                    "new york is also called the big apple",
                    "nyc is nice",
                    "people abbreviate new york city as nyc",
                    "the capital of great britain is london",
                    "london is in the uk",
                    "london is in england",
                    "london is in great britain",
                    "it rains a lot in london",
                    "london hosts the british museum",
                    "new york is great and so is london",
                    "i like london better than new york",
                    "I love fruits mate",
                    "I usually eat apples",
                    "we should go for bananas or other fruits"])
y_train_text = [["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],["new york"],
                ["new york"],["london"],["london"],["london"],["london"],
                ["london"],["london"],["new york","london"],["new york","london"],["Fruits"],["Fruits"],["Fruits"]]

X_test = np.array(['nice day in nyc',
                   'welcome to london',
                   'london is rainy',
                   'it is raining in britian',
                   'it is raining in britian and the big apple',
                   'it is raining in britian and nyc',
                   'hello welcome to new york. enjoy it here and london too',
                   'how about fruits like apples or something today ?',
                   'shall we go for apples ?'])
target_names = ['New York', 'London','Fruits']



    classifier = Pipeline([
        ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
        ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(SVC(kernel="linear",decision_function_shape='ovo')))])

classifier.fit(X_train, Y)
predicted = classifier.predict(X_test)
all_labels = mlb.inverse_transform(predicted)
```

This sample code gives the following output :

```
nice day in nyc => new york
welcome to london => london
london is rainy => london
it is raining in britian => 
it is raining in britian and the big apple => new york
it is raining in britian and nyc => new york
hello welcome to new york. enjoy it here and london too => london, new york
how about fruits like apples or something today ? => Fruits
shall we go for apples ? => Fruits
```

Comment: Double check that none of the values in y_train_text are empty strings

Comment: Why are you using TfidfVectorizer and TfidfTransformer both. TfidfVectorizer will internally use TfidfTransformer, if you want that. I dont see how this is helping you. Are you following any tutorial? If yes, then please link to it. And also post some samples so that we can duplicate the issue.

Comment: @aberger : done, they are all proper values. I did an adapted version of this code from stackO, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10527953/revisions. I've been modifying the vectorizer. in order to get better results. I forgot to remove the transformer (since not useful here). Thanks for pointing out this.

Comment: @VivekKumar : i answered in the last comment^^ (forgot to mention you)

Comment: Can you show some sample data (X, Y) on which to reproduce this?

Comment: See the edited part of my post.. I'm thinking I may be missing a parameter (or a spec of the model)

Comment: I am not able to duplicate the issue. I am getting at least 1 output for all entries. For the entry in which you are getting blank (`it is raining in britian`), I am getting `('Fruits', 'london'),`... So maybe its an issue in the way you print the results or library version. I am using 0.18.

Comment: Did you get the answer ?